# Find triples of solutions for the equation $a+2b^2+3c^3+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{2}{b^2}+\frac{3}{c^3}=12$

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I find the triples of solutions ($a,b,c$) for the equation $a+2b^2+3c^3+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{2}{b^2}+\frac{3}{c^3}=12$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume $a,b,c > 0$.

$a + \frac{1}{a} \ge 2$ by say the AM-GM inequality, with equality iff $a =1$.
Similarly $2b^2 + \frac{2}{b^2} \ge 4$ and $3c^3 + \frac{3}{c^3} \ge 6$ with equality when they are equal to $1$.

Combining these gives $a+2b^2+3c^3+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{2}{b^2}+\frac{3}{c^3}\ge12$ with equality iff $a=b=c=1$